# Write numerical data to a text file: matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab

I need some help in converting these Matlab instructions to Python:

```
var = [1.222222 2.33333333 3.4444444];
fmt = [repmat(' %1.4e', 1, size(var, 2)), '\n'];

fid = fopen('myfile.txt','w');
fprintf(fid, fmt, var);
fclose(fid);
```

Which writes in the file:

```
 1.2222e+00 2.3333e+00 3.4444e+00
```

In particular, as far as repmat is concerned, I know I should use tile, I am not sure how to include the formatting.

Comment: Did you try to search for an answer on the Internet? You can use similar numpy method: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.matlib.repmat.html

Comment: so far I've tried

    with open ('psi'+fileout,'w') as f:
        fmt=[np.matlib.repmat('%1.4e', 1, flux2D.shape[1]), '\n']
        np.savetxt(f, -np.transpose(flux2D), fmt)

    f.close()

    it fails as fmt has wront shape

Comment: Include your attempt in the question please

Comment: Also, you don't need to do this much work even in Matlab

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab, you can format an entire array that way. In Python it's much simpler. You can use [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt) to save the whole array with a single format:

```
var = ...
np.savetxt(file, var, fmt='%14e')
```

File can be a file name or file handle. So if you want to check the output, for example, just pass in `sys.stdout` for the first argument.